# How to implement document flavour in Oak storage?

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I am new to jackrabbit Oak, I have been looking into documentations but not finding the right approach, I read Oak comes with two node storage flavors: **segment and document**. I understood that the segment flavor is for standalone application so I wanted to implement the document flavor implementation not MongoDB or RDS, **I wanna save my files in File System using MemoryDocumentStore**, I am assuming Using MemoryDocumentStore I will be able to save files in file system and retrieve, I am not sure if I am right ?

> What is the difference between segment and document implementation and how do I see the tree in Oak??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MemoryDocumentStore is only for testing; it doesn't persist the data at all.

If you want to use a DocumentStore, RDB and Mongo persistence are currently your only options.

Are you sure that the SegmentStore is not what you need?

Comment: thanks for the response can I use SegmentStore for distributed server/clustered application ?

Comment: If you need clustering, you'll need the DocumentNodeStore indeed.

Comment: DocumentNodeStore  is MongoDocumentStore/RDBDocumentStore right ??